# leaflet how to remove an icon from a marker

Tags: leaflet, icons

I have few thousands of markers on my map. Some of them of [pulsing icons](https://github.com/mapshakers/leaflet-icon-pulse) according to users request.

At one point, the user wish to remove them. Given the marker that he points at, how can I simply remove the icon.

To add it I have:

```
var icon = L.icon.pulse({html:iconOptions.html, fillColor: iconOptions.fillColor, color:iconOptions.color, iconSize:iconOptions.iconSize, animate: true});
marker.setIcon(icon);
```

To remove the icon I tried:

```
var icon = marker.getIcon(); //getIcon doesnt exists :(
marker.remove(icon)
```

one thing for sure, I cannot remove the marker as it has other valuable information and the icon is not a layer that I can do clearLayer.

Comment: Do you want to remove the pulsing feature, or hide the marker?

Comment: @ghybs I wish to remove the pulsing feature only and maintain the marker (the marker should not be removed)